# Converting .tif files to vector MBTiles by using gdal_polygonize

Tags: gdal, geotiff-tiff, mbtiles, gdal-polygonize

I am trying to use GDAL 2.2.2 and the `gdal_polygonize`command to convert a TIF into vector [MBtiles](https://docs.mapbox.com/help/glossary/mbtiles/) from the link:

https://github.com/geostarters/gdal_snipets

I run the following command on the tif as in the link:

```
gdal_polygonize.py -8 -nomask -b 1 input_4326.tif \
-f "MBTiles" output.mbtiles \
-lco NAME=nameoutput \
-dsco WRITE_BOUNDS=YES \
-dsco MAX_FEATURES=20000000 \
-dsco MAXZOOM=15
```

However I get the following ERROR:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
> "/usr/bin/gdal_polygonize.py", line 180, in 
> dst_ds = drv.CreateDataSource( dst_filename )
> AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'CreateDataSource'

It seems to me that I do not have the GDAL MBTiles Driver 'installed':

https://gdal.org/drivers/raster/mbtiles.html

I installed gdal onto Uubntu 16.04 via the terminal.

Is there anything I can do to get this working?

Comment: You can test if you have the driver with `ogrinfo --format mbtiles`.

Answer (score 1):

Your main problem is that your GDAL version 2.2.2 is too old for creating MBTiles vector dataset. You must upgrade.

From the MBTiles documentation https://gdal.org/drivers/raster/mbtiles.html

> Starting with GDAL 2.3, the MBTiles driver has read and write support for MBTiles vector datasets. For standalone Mapbox Vector Tile files or set of MVT files, see the MVT driver. Note: vector write support requires GDAL to be built with GEOS.

You may be hit by some other problems even with a proper GDAL version. I made a test with GDAL 3.1.4 and the following command worked for me:

```
gdal_polygonize.py -8 -nomask -b 1 P4433H.tif -f "MBTiles" output.mbtiles -lco NAME=nameoutput
```

By the documentation WRITE_BOUNDS is only for raster tiles. MAXZOOM and MAX_FEATURES should be OK to use but I had to drop them as well.

Comment: Thank you. The only problem I am having is trying to figure out how to "upgrade" gdal to the newest version from 2.2.2. I cannot figure out how to do this. I tried "pip install GDAL==3.1.4" but keep getting red "ERROR: Failed building wheel for GDAL
"

Comment: There are many alternatives https://gdal.org/download.html#binaries. Also Ubuntugis unstable has GDAL 3.2 https://launchpad.net/~ubuntugis/+archive/ubuntu/ubuntugis-unstable.